# check all check boxes with just one click

Tags: magento2, ajax, jquery, checkbox

I have one check box on the top of the page.
scenario: I want to check all checkboxes on each line by just clicking that top check box and uncheck all the checkboxes on each line by unchecking that top check box.

I have pagination so I want to work the above scenario only for the current page, not other pages.

Comment: you can use `.prop("checked", true)` if you are using jquery

Comment: true....but how to check all the checkboxes on the same page simultaneously with just one click

Comment: assign them same class name and add prop to that classname it will check all the checkboxes

Comment: nice idea....thankx a lot..Its worked for me